# Merge 2 sets of intervals while constraining each interval from set1 to the bounds of set2

Tags: algorithm, intervals, overlap

Here's an image illustrating what I mean:

[image]

Basically I want to merge set1 into set2, but each interval from set1 is not allowed to exist unless it is contained within the bounds of an interval from set2.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

PS: My next task would be to figure out how to merge *n* number of *set1*s (i.e. green layers that may overlap with each other) into a set2 with the same rules applying... but I'll start with this first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an algorithm for such a merge in JavaScript -- it should be easy to reproduce in other programming languages:

```js
function merge(segments1, segments2) {
    const result = [];
    let i = -1, start1 = -Infinity, end1 = -Infinity, 
        j = -1, start2 = -Infinity; end2 = -Infinity;
    while (i < segments1.length || j < segments2.length) {
        if (end1 <= start2) { // get next from segments1
            i++;
            start1 = i < segments1.length ? segments1[i][0] : Infinity;
            end1 = i < segments1.length ? segments1[i][1] : Infinity;
        } else if (end2 <= start1) { // flush and get next from segments2
            if (start2 < end2) result.push([start2, end2]);
            j++;
            start2 = j < segments2.length ? segments2[j][0] : Infinity;
            end2 = j < segments2.length ? segments2[j][1] : Infinity;
        } else { // overlap
            if (start2 < start1) {
                result.push([start2, start1]);
                start2 = start1;
            }
            start1 = Math.min(end2, end1);
            result.push([start2, start1]);
            start2 = start1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Sample input
const segments1 = [[6, 7], [8, 11], [12, 14], [15, 18], [19, 20], [22, 23], 
                   [25, 26], [27, 28], [30, 31], [33, 35]],
      segments2 = [[6, 10], [11, 14], [16, 17], [18, 21], [22, 24], [24, 26],
                   [27, 28], [29, 31], [33, 34], [35, 36]];
// Merge and output
const result = merge(segments1, segments2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

To merge multiple sets of segments, you would just call the above function like this:

```
merged = merge(green1, grey)
merged = merge(green2, merged)
merged = merge(green3, merged)
// ... etc
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much! Do you have any suggestions for extra tags I could add to help future googlers? Or do you figure this is a pretty specific use-case...

Edit: Gist for a sample PHP implementation, with the ability to track any green layer meta-data if desired (applicable for my use-case). https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a0f870b77a87d0b22c5ab89db90756ee

Comment: You're welcome ;-) I think the current tags are fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add all the intervals from the set2 to the result.
2. Add all the intervals from the set1 to the result, “cutting” or completely removing them if they don’t fit completely in an interval of set2.
3. Merge all the overlapping intervals in the resulting set.

To efficiently implement the second step you could sort the intervals in set2 by the first coordinate and use binary search. For the 3rd step https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/